# Synchronize a jCombobox with a MySQL Table

Tags: java, mysql, swing, jcombobox

I've created a database application with the NetBeans GUI-Designer.

GUI with Comboboxes (Bound to MySQL databasetables user and team):
[image: Combobox1 & 2 to select a user and/or a team]

on Button new -> jDialog - executes a query to store a new user in database:
[image: jDialog with textfield, save and cancel]

Problem: Combobox is updated at the programstart but not while running the program.

Question: Is it possible to update the entries in my combobox directly when a new user or team is saved? And how could I Implement this?

Edit: Here is what I do when clicking on the `saveButton` in the `JDialog`:

```
int k=st.executeUpdate(
    "INSERT INTO User (username) " + " VALUES ('"+ name + "')");
//Here I'd like to update the jComboBox1 directly if possible
Outerclass.jComboBox1...; 
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "User is successfully saved");'
```

Answer (score 4):

Just update your component's [`ComboBoxModel`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/ComboBoxModel.html) when you insert a new user in the database. If this is not helpful, please provide an [sscce](http://sscce.org/) that exhibits the problem.

Addendum: Given a reference to a `JComboBox`,

```
private final JComboBox combo = new JComboBox();
```

you can update its model, as shown below. This example adds `name` to the beginning of the list, but [`SortedComboBoxModel`](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/11/11/sorted-combo-box-model/) is an appealing alternative.

```
DefaultComboBoxModel model = (DefaultComboBoxModel) combo.getModel();
model.insertElementAt(name, 0);
```

Addendum: More simply, use the method available to the `combo` itself,

```
combo.insertElementAt(name, 0);
```

Comment: Here is what I do when clicking on the savebutton in the jDialog:  'int k=st.executeUpdate("INSERT INTO User (username) " + " VALUES ('"+ name + "')");'


    //Here i would like to update my jComboBox1 which is in the other class.   



    'Oterclass.jComboBox1( ????here I'd like to update the combobox directly, possible??);'
         
    'JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"User is successfully saved");'

Comment: The class the updates the database needs a reference to the comboBox so you can update the comboBox. Or your class that updates the database needs to fire an event indicating the database was updated and the class that has a reference to the comboBox needs to listen for this event.

Comment: @user1036529: Please update your question, where code will be more readable.

Comment: no need for a type-cast - if you use api on the combo itself :-)

Comment: `DefaultComboBoxModel model = (DefaultComboBoxModel) combo.getModel(); model.insertElementAt(name, 0);` that works only if the Combobox is not bound. In my case the combo is bound to a userlist from a table user and as soon as i bind the combox it's not working anymore.. any idea?

Answer (score 1):

I ran into a similar problem: if you enter anything into the database, that is supposed to be reflected in the JComboBox, then you can't change the values of that combo box. It would be great if you could add things to the JComboBox "on the fly" directly, but you have to get that data, create a new ComboBoxModel from it, and then set your JComboBox to that new model.

Here, I use DefaultComboBoxModel, which can either take an array of objects (usually strings) or a vector. If you use vectors to represent your underlying data model, that's a lot easier, since vectors are dynamic data structures.

My code:

```
Vector<String> s = new Vector<String>();
try {
    // I'm using prepared statements, get the ResultSet however you like
    ResultSet rs = myPreparedStatement.executeQuery(); 
    while ( rs.next() ) {
        // Change "1" to whatever column holds your data
        s.add(rs.getString(1)); 
    }
} catch (SQLException ex) {
    ex.printStackTrace(); // or whatever
}
DefaultComboBoxModel jcbModel = new DefaultComboBoxModel(s);
jcb.setModel(jcbModel);
```

EDIT: Remember that ResultSet columns are 1-indexed, not 0-indexed! Gets me every time.

Comment: _you can't change the values of that combo box_ - that's wrong, why do you think so?