# how to update the jcombobox immediately when the table in database get updated in java

Tags: java, swing, jdbc, jframe, jcombobox

I am working on java application.I have two frames in application.I want to reflect data entered in one frame into another frame run time.

[image]

As shown in above window when I press submit button in supplier window combobox in puchase window should get updated immediately.
What necessary changes should I make?

here is my code of frame1 to store data in database :

```
public void btnSubmitAction(ActionEvent e){

    String custId,custNm;

    if(txtSupplierID.getText().equals("") || txtSupplierName.getText().equals("") )
    {
        System.out.println("Please enter valid information!!!!!!!");
    }
    else
    {
        try{
            setConnectin();
            String str = "Insert into SupplierMasterTable values(?,?)";
            pstmt = conn.prepareStatement(str);
            pstmt.setString(1,txtSupplierID.getText());
            pstmt.setString(2, txtSupplierName.getText());
            int x = pstmt.executeUpdate();
            System.out.println("Supplier registered successfully");
            txtSupplierID.setText("");
            txtSupplierName.setText("");
            conn.close();
        }catch(Exception e1){
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

}
```

And here is my code of frame2 to get data from database :

```
    JComboBox comboBoxVenderName = new JComboBox();
    comboBoxVenderName.setFont(new Font("Times New Roman", Font.PLAIN, 15));
    comboBoxVenderName.setBounds(144, 88, 137, 21);
    panel.add(comboBoxVenderName);

    try{
        setConnectin();
        String str = "select * from SupplierMasterTable";
        stmt = conn.createStatement();
        rs = stmt.executeQuery(str);
        while(rs.next())
        {
            comboBoxVenderName.addItem(rs.getString("Supplier_Name"));
        }
        conn.close();
    }catch(Exception e2){
        e2.printStackTrace();
    }
```

I have gone through following links but does not get the feasible solution :

[Immediate update to JCombobox in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14171600/immediate-update-to-jcombobox-in-java)

[Synchronize a jCombobox with a MySQL Table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8267635/synchronize-a-jcombobox-with-a-mysql-table)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> JComboBox comboBoxVenderName = new JComboBox();

Don't create a new combo box when you want to refresh the data.

Instead you should create a new DefaultComboBoxModel and add the data to the model. Then you update the data in the existing combo box by using:

```
comboBox.setModel( the updated model );
```

Also, don't use a null layout!!! You should not be using the setBounds() method. Swing was designed to be used with layout managers.

Comment: can you please explain in brief?I have tried to use `DefaultComboBoxModel` with reference with first link in question.But I does not get the result as a want.Please help

Comment: I did explain it briefly. You add data to the model and then add the model to the combo box. Post your [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org/) (that doesn't use the database) that demonstrates your problem. That is create a simple frame that contains a combo box loaded with data and a "Refresh" button. The refresh button will simply load hardcoded data into a model and then update the combo box. Prove that the basic concept works. Once you get this refresh method working you make the method dynamic by using your database.